# Is there any alternative way to position images in a page at a particular place on different resolutions

Tags: css, media-queries, css-position

Here iam trying to add 2 images in the section one is center aligned and 2nd one is positioned beside the 1st image, but i'am getting problem in different resolutions for the 2nd image by using the below code is there any alternative way to be consistent in the posioning across the resolutions?
Refer the image.

```css
    main.uni-design {
  background-image: url("../images/ban2.jpg");
  max-height: 1000px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

img.mob {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -23px;
  right: 0%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  img.mob {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -23px;
    right: 7%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  img.mob {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -23px;
    right: 16%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
  img.mob {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -23px;
    right: 23%;
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
    img.mob {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -23px;
      right: 27%;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<main class="uni-design pt-5">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>For all devices</h3>
    <h3 class="bt">Unique design</h3>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <img src="images/tab.png" class="img-fluid pt-4" />
    <img src="images/mobnew.png" class="img-fluid mob" />
  </div>
</main>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a working snippet or replace the path of images to similar images which are on server

Comment: You could wrap the images in a div (with `position: relative`) and then just position the mobile image slightly to the bottom right of that instead of the whole container?

Comment: @coops yes, i wrapped both the images and positoned the mobile image to the wrapper instead of the whole section, now i'am able to see the better result.

Comment: @AbhilashPoojary Great, glad i could help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used `margin` to overlay the mobile image with flexbox method. I hope this will be helpful for you.

```css
.res-design {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.res-design .mobile {
    align-self: flex-end;
    margin: 0 0 0 -8%;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main>
    <div class="container my-5">
        <div class="res-design">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400.png" class="img-fluid tab" />
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x200.png" class="img-fluid mobile" />
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```